# How to detect if a tabified QDockWidget is the active tab

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have multiple dock widgets tabified in my Qt 5.1 application. I want to know which tab is currently active (whether or not it currently has focus), but I don't see how to get that information programmatically.

I've tried `QWidget::IsVisible()`, `QWidget::IsVisibleTo()`, and examining the list returned by `QMainWindow::tabifiedDockWidgets()`, which excludes the widget sent in as a param and so cannot provide the order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check if some part of dock widget is visible using the following code:

```
bool really_visible = !widget->visibleRegion().isEmpty();
```

I tested that result value depends on which dock widget tab is active.